# taking bike on vacation

Tags: security

I'm planning to take my bike on this year vacation but I have certain dilemmas where and how to keep bike secure during my stay. Bike is nothing fancy (MTB, 26" wheels, full suspension bike with Manitou shocks, aluminum frame, new SLX groupset, Fox DOSS seat post...) more of a sentimental value because I put too much work and effort in maintaing it.

First of all, I'm staying at a hotel which doesn't have secure room for storing bikes and management doesn't allow keeping bikes in room or on balcony. Hotel only has bike racks at the entrance to each hotel wing (some of theme are covered with 'security' cameras) and most guest keep their bikes locked there. At night, those racks are in dark and I have no idea if I'll be able to see it from my room.

My concern is that by keeping my bike with other bikes (usually cheaper ones), it will stick out and be nice 'target' due to higher end parts and components.

The other option is to keep bike inside my car on unsecured parking lot (no street light, no surveillance) which is even further away from hotel and my car has no alarm to hear if someone tries to open it.

My bike will be unattended during night, and most of the day while not riding it (meals, going on beach...) I also considered leaving my bike at home and renting bike but prices are outrageous - so it isn't an option.

To be honest, at the moment I'm still searching for a decent bike lock so I have yet to solve that part of a problem (and I'm probably little paranoid when it comes to bikes).

Any ideas and suggestions how to secure bike (and enjoy vacation) are more than welcome.

Comment: Depending on where you're going on vacation, rent a bike when you want to use it?

Comment: I already stated that renting is not an option since prices are too high for my standard (7 days of renting is cca. 150 Euros, even more if your rent for shorter period of time... bikes are poor quality and maintenance IMO). Btw, location is an island in Croatia, beautiful nature and great tracks for riding so it would be pity not to explore it by bike.

Comment: An option, as your bike has sentimental value, buy a bike to take with you (and take out travel insurance that covers the bike if it is worth more than you can afford to loose). Sell it when you get home.

Comment: If I could afford to buy new bike for this special occasion, renting bike wouldn't be a problem. Also, IMO buying stuff impulsively and then selling it is usually throwing away money because you'll never get same amount back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try leaving the bike in your car, but covered with a dark blanket so that its not visible at night, it would be even better concealed if you took the wheels with you into your room at night as it could make the blankets profile flatter (handlebars turned to be inline with the frame).

If you dont mind taking it apart even more (pedals and wheels) you could even get a bike box to put it in, when you cover it with a dark covering then it would present a flat surface in your car which would be almost invisible in the dark.

Additionally, park near a street light or as close to the entrance as possible so its covered by the "security cameras" you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Talk nicely to the place you're staying.  Generally there's someone who lives on site permanently, and they may have better facilities.  You will have to slide them some money for consideration, but pop your bike in a  lockup garage would be ideal.

Is there another accommodation in the area that does have better bike storage?  Staying there might work better.

Is there a bike shop in the area that could store your bike?  Even a 24 hour service station might be more secure.   Totally tip them though.

Another thought is to remove at least the front wheel, and store the bike in your locked car overnight.  That way if its stolen then your insurer is unable to say "you didn't take adequate precautions."

Comment: Or take a small waterproof tarpaulin with you and store the bike in your room.  Use the tarp to protect the floor.  Be super careful getting the bike in and out to not damage anything.   This would be "asking forgiveness, not permission."

Comment: Place I'll be staying at is an island (national park, so pretty isolated) with only one hotel, and maybe few houses and one or two small shops. There are several bike rental shops but I doubt they would allow me to keep my bike there. On the other hand, hotel guest are allowed to keep all sort of beach toys and even pets are allowed! Unfortunately bikes are prohibited :(